# AngularJS & AppGyver Steroids - Adding a dependency

Tags: angularjs, restangular, steroids

I've been playing around with AppGyver [steroids](/questions/tagged/steroids) as well as [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) and decided to use RestAngular for my REST API calls. But I'm having trouble adding the dependancy to the app.

In the controller I've included the dependancy:

```
var mainModule = angular.module('SteroidsAngular', ['restangular'])
```

I've also included the script on my pages:

```
<script src="javascripts/restangular/dist/restangular.js"></script>
```

Running the app or the pages in a web browser (before and after I've tried injecting RestAngular into controllers) just causes blank alerts or browser dialogs to show.
What would be the best way to get this to work?

Comment: See you browser console log for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a Underscore.js dependancy which I failed to load up. Found this through the console.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try `$ steroids generate ng-scaffold` in a new Steroids project for an example how to implement Restangular in Steroids.